# Rails scaffold erb templates not being used during generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I'm bulding an application with lots of simple scaffolds in rails 4.2.5.1 . I customized my erb scaffold templates and placed them in **lib/templates/erb/scaffold**.

However, when I run *rails g scaffold Course* , the new templates are just ignored. No warning is given of might be happening. Any insight on how to debug the problem will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Juliano, Did you find the solution to this problem?